Delphi false "ifdef" directive editor colouring
I compile my code with include files defining compiler directives, not in project settings, because it's much easier.
Delphi does not interpret this at the editor level, so this makes parts of my source code grayed out in Delphi 12 falsely.
How can I disable this colouring feature? (and only this)
Or which editor colour should I change? I found no match for it and the example coloured code sample in Options/Editor/Color is missing this kind of code part and I'm afraid it's not in the "Element" list either.
Edit: even if I define that directive in compiler settings, that won't help. Even after a successful compilation. So I want to disable this color feature completely.
Delphi 11 does not have this, so going back there.

"Delphi does not interpret this at the editor level" - yes, it does. "so this makes parts of my source code grayed out in Delphi 12 falsely" - I have projects with conditionals defined in INC files and the editor colors/greys the code appropriately, no problem.

I guess it works in most cases,  but maybe not for a file which is not part of the project, or switching projects inside the project group makes it, I don't know what caused this, not really motivated to find out this. I can live without this feature, no problem for me., thanks for the feedback.

You can define an opacity percent value for inactive code in Tools > Options > User Interface > Editor > Language dialog on Error Insight tab.
So in order to prevent inactive code to be faded set Inactive Code Opacity Percent to 100.
EDIT: In Delphi 12 this setting can be found at Tools > Options > Editor > Language dialog on Error Insight tab.

Thank you, on D12 update 2 it's actually at Tools > Options > Editor > Language > Error insight

Yes I know that in Delphi 12 this setting is at different place but when I was searching for online documentation to link for some reason all results from google point to Delphi 11 documentation and Embarcadero didn't make any easy for switching between  documentation of different Delphi versions. Naming Delphi edition on specific cities doesn't help either. If they could at least keep Delphi version in URL but no. I long the days of Delphi XE editions where you simply change part of the URL for XE2, XE4 or whatever.
